# Remove the past dates manually

Tags: java, android-studio, date

I am using a date picker library in Android Studio using Java. I want to remove dates in the past from the date picker but I want to do it manually.

ex: The below code shows the date picker library with removed past dates:

```java
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(Create_Event_Activity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int date) {
        create_event_activity_event_ending_date.setText(year+" "+month+" "+date);
    }
},year,month,date);
                            
/*datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());*/
                      
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.compareTo());
datePickerDialog.show();
```

The above code just disables the past dates for the user but I want to give the time manually as a string format like:

```
String date = "09/04/2022";
```

And the date picker just disables all the past dates from this date.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: I do not do Android work. So I’ve not verified the code in this Answer. The Android documentation is vague, so I am not entirely sure of the behavior of `setMinDate`.

## Pass a `long`, a count of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00Z

The [setMinDate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker#setMinDate(long)) method takes a `long`. The documentation is tragically vague, but seems to say that number represents the number of milliseconds since the first moment of 1970 as seen in UTC, with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

Determining a date requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. A moment can be “tomorrow” in Tokyo Japan while simultaneously “yesterday” in Toledo Ohio US.

### *java.time*

Use the modern *java.time* classes rather than the miserable legacy date-time classes.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2022 , Month.SEPTEMBER , 4 ) ;
```

Or, you can access the runtime environment’s current default time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
```

To determine a moment from a date, we need to specify a time of day. I assume you want the first moment of that date.

A day does not necessarily start at 00:00:00, and may start at another time such as 01:00. So we must let *java.time* determine the first moment. And we need that time zone again, to do so.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay ( z ) ;
```

Extract an `Instant` to represent a moment as seen in UTC (an offset of zero).

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant () ;
```

Get the number of milliseconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z to that moment.

```
long millis = instant.toEpochMilli() ;
```

Pass that count of millis to your date picker.

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate( millis ) ;
```

---

The *java.time* classes are built into Android 26+. For earlier Android, the latest tooling provides most of the functionality via “API desugaring”. If that fails you, use [the back-port](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) of *java.time* packaged expressly for Android in the [*ThreeTen Android Backport*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) library.